# catch without try and try without catch errors

Tags: java

Just copy and past a code from the Java Head First Book into a text editor but cant compile it with javac in command prompt ,getting catch without try and try without catch erros it is a code from a learning book so it should work ,have no idea whats wrong.

Here´s the code:

```
package chap05;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GameHelper {

  private static final String alphabet = "abcdefg";
  private int gridLength = 7;
  private int gridSize = 49;
  private int [] grid = new int[gridSize];
  private int comCount = 0;


  public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
     String inputLine = null;
     System.out.print(prompt + "  ");
     try {
       BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       inputLine = is.readLine();
       if (inputLine.length() == 0 ){  return null; 
     } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
     }
     return inputLine.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: Check it out brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes there might be a printing error, In above code the if block is not closed properly. Modify as below

```
 if (inputLine.length() == 0 ){  return null; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your if block is not closed properly:

```
   if (inputLine.length() == 0 ){  return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (inputLine.length() == 0 ){  return null;
```

here you missed a `}`

Comment: Already rectified but still gives me the exactly same 2 erros,anymore insight?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors. Please copy and paste the error message you get